# No "tab to move to next input element" in dynamically-generated HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some javascript that's generated upon the user clicking a button:

```
htmlstring  = ''+          
'<div class="input_holder">'+
'<div class="as_input_holder"><input tabindex="1" class="as_input form-control-small" id="name">'+
'<div class="as_input_holder_footer">Name</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="as_input_holder"><input tabindex="2" class="as_input form-control-small" id="number">'+
'<div class="as_input_holder_footer">Number</div>'+
'</div>'+
'<div class="as_input_holder"><input tabindex="3" class="as_input form-control-small" id="rank">'+
'<div class="as_input_holder_footer">Rank</div>'+
'</div>'+                                   
'</div>';

$('#as_body').html(htmlstring);
```

The `as_body` id is within *another* dynamically-generated javascript window already (so it doesn't exist when the page loads), and the code works almost perfectly, but I cannot for the life of me get tabbing from input field to input field to work.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: maybe you have got the same tabindex values somewhere else in the page already? Not sure what will happen if you have duplicates.

Comment: Usually when you generate code you have to reimplements your jquery listener. Jquery search for listener at the beginning of the page so you have to create them again once your code is done generating

Comment: I just copied this into a fiddle and tabbing works for me in all major browsers so it has to be something related to your project and not this code. Are you disabling tabbing somewhere else in your project possibly?

Comment: @macksol possibly?  I'm using the sweetalert library to generate the "popup" on the user's screen that I add this content into - but maybe something in that code disables tabs?  I will look more deeply into the code...

Comment: You know what - it may have more to do with the sweet alert library than it does javascript.  There seems to be other users experiencing somewhat similar issues;  https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/127

Comment: Nice, I think that's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that when you add your tabIndexes Dynamically the browser fail to recognize the property. What i would suggest is remove the tabindex properties from your dynamically generated script. When you append your "htmlString" to the DOM look for the newly inserted entries "as_input_holder" iterate through them and add the tabIndex

```
var tabIndex = 1;
$("#as_body").find('.as_input_holder input').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('tabIndex', tabIndex);
    tabIndex++;
})
```

This way you will attach the tabIndex to your JS object and this should work on theory :). I haven't test that it's just a suggestion but i think this will solve your problem.

Good luck!